# Is the variable created if there is exception in the value expression

Tags: python, exception

In a `try/except` block, does the variable get created if the initializer code raises exception?

```
try:
  a = some_func()
except:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

The following sample code

```py
try:
  a = 1 / 0
except:
  pass

print(a)
```

raises the "NameError: name 'a' is not defined" error.

Answer (score 0):

The variable will not be assigned to. However, if this occurs in a function, the *name* `a` is still considered local and could shadow a global even if it is not assigned to. Locality is determined when the function is defined, not when it is called.

```
a = 5


def foo():
    try:
        a = 1/0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass

    print(a)  # Still raises a NameError, rather than printing 5
```